# Rename all files in a subdirectory while keeping the same location

Tags: bash

Inside my parent folder, I have a script and many folders. Inside those folders contain arbitrarily named text files. When I run my script to rename to files, the new renamed files end up in the parent folder. How do I write the script so that the newly named files remain in their original folder?

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name '*txt') ; do
    name=$(parse text for correct name)
    mv "$file" "${name}.txt"
done
```

Comment: If the files are arbitrarily named, don't do `for f in $(find)`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 3):

Your biggest challenge is simply separating the `path` from the orignal `filename` so you can move the original file to `path/name.txt`. You can use **parameter expansion/substring removal** to accomplish the task, e.g. (with `line` being the original filename read)

```
while read -r line; do
    name=$(parse text for correct name)  # parse your new name as needed
    fname="${line##*/}"                  # isolate the filename in line
    dname="${line%"$fname"}"             # remove fname from end of line for path
    mv "$line" "${dname}/${name}.txt"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are not specifying the directory in your `mv` command.  Since your script is invoked from the parent directory, the renamed files are ending up there.

Revise it this way:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name '*txt'); do
    # grab the directory of the file being renamed
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    name=$(parse text for correct name)
    mv "$file" "$dir/${name}.txt"
done
```

As per the suggestion, you could rewrite your loop this way.  This would protect you from white spaces and globs in your file names, if any:

```
while read -r file; do
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    name=$(parse text for correct name)
    mv "$file" "$dir/${name}.txt"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*txt')
```